# Watir-webdriver: get same screenshot images for all failed scenarios

Tags: ruby, cucumber, screenshot, watir-webdriver

I've set screenshots to be taken when a scenario fails, but my html report shows the same screenshot on all failed scenarios. Can anyone help and let me know how I can get unique screenshots taken for each failed scenario.

Here is my code in my env.rb:

```
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.failed?
     @browser.driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
     embed("screenshot.png", "image/png")
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are saving the screenshot to the same file each time (ie overwriting the previous screenshot each time). The report has also linked all the images to the same place. This is why you get the same image everywhere.

You need to provide a unique name for the screenshot.

For example, you could timestamp (with date and time) the images:

```
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.failed?
     screenshot_file = "screenshot-#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')}.png"
     @browser.driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_file)
     embed(screenshot_file, "image/png")
  end   
end
```

Comment: Once again! Justin, many many thanks. If I ever see you, I owe you a drink

Answer (score 1):

Justin has the answer,  But while timestamps are fine, they make it harder when looking at the files to know which one was for what scenario.  When I run tests while creating and debugging, I often don't even look at the html report, I just look at the generated screenshot, so in that case it is doubly useful to have more logical names.

So the code I use looks like this, and embeds using the scenario name

```
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.failed?
    screenshot = "./FAILED_#{scenario.name.gsub(' ','_').gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z_]/, '')}.png"
    @browser.driver.save_screenshot(screenshot)
    encoded_img = @browser.driver.screenshot_as(:base64)
    embed("data:image/png;base64,#{encoded_img}",'image/png')
  end
end
```

An even more robust approach, dealing with scenario outlines and appending timestamp is described in [this 'Two Four One' blog posting](http://twofourone.blogspot.com/2011/04/making-your-cukes-more-awesomer-with.html)  so far I've not needed to go that far, but I may pull in stuff from it to deal with scenario outlines.

Comment: Thanks Chuck, i'll give that a go. Sounds good, i'm pretty versatile but i'll chat with my dev team and see what they prefer. Once again Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

for the ones using RSpec, there is a really nice implementation of HtmlFormatter  in the [watir-rspec](https://github.com/watir/watir-rspec) project