# Watir-webdriver: get screenshot images for all failed scenarios [for Test::Unit]

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I want my tests to save screen shots for all failed scenarios.

I found one good post "[Watir-webdriver: get same screenshot images for all failed scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013103/watir-webdriver-get-same-screenshot-images-for-all-failed-scenarios/16015667#16015667)" about this question, and I put the code suggested by Justin in my env.rb and it does not work well. I am not sure if this is because I am not using Cucumber?

Given a typical example test case I have:

```
require "rubygems"
require "test/unit"
require "watir-webdriver"
require "page-object"
require "./home_page"


class LogInTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  # Called before every test method runs. Can be used
  # to set up fixture information.
  def setup
    @browser ||= Watir::Browser.new :firefox
  end

  # Called after every test method runs. Can be used to tear
  # down fixture information.

  def teardown
    @browser.close
  end

  # Fake test
  def test_fail
    @home_page = HomePage.new(@browser)
    @home_page.visit
    @log_in_page = @home_page.go_to_log_in
    @all_deals = @log_in_page.log_in("test_user","test_pass")
    assert @browser.title.include? "- hello world"
  end
end
```

How do I make a generic methods to save all screenshots for failed tests to a target folder?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the question you referenced will not work since it was written for Cucumber. However, the same can be adapted to Test::Unit.

Try switching your `teardown` to:

```
def teardown
  #Save image if test fails
  unless passed?
    #Where to save the image and the file name
    screenshot_file = "screenshot-#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')}.png"

    #Save the image
    @browser.driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_file)
  end

  #Close the browser
  @browser.close
end
```